# How to update OSM data using osm2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have already loaded osm data into postgresql earlier. Now I want to update the database. I have downloaded the pbf file from geofabrik. How I can update the database without deleting the existing Tables?

Answer (score 10):

If you have imported a planet or extract some time ago and have now downloaded a *(much) newer* planet or extract:

It does not really make sense to do any updating as I think calculating and applying the diff will not save you time. Just re-run osm2pgsql again and it will remove the tables and create new ones resulting in updated data.

If you want to keep your data updated *continuously*:

Download diff files provided by different providers (e.g. Geofabrik), see [Planet.osm/diffs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/diffs) for more information. Then use e.g. [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) in combination with `osm2pgsql --append`. [Switch2OSM](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/) with section "Updating" might also provide hints.

Comment: I have tried but it returns 

Processing: Node(82248k 663.3k/s) Way(4383k 8.56k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)Killed

Comment: So it did not read the relations and did not even reach the writing stage. Did it not read anything for a while and you stopped it or did it exit by itself? Could it be a memory issue? Which extract are you trying to import? Could you try with a smaller extract first?

Comment: "Did it not read anything for a while and you stopped it " Happenned. Database were parged. Now no table exist. I am in great trouble

Comment: WHat about updating using flat nodes files? I have not the temp tables in my database but I kept the flat nodes files. Do I need to download the entire PBF file again or just the diff file? Consider it is a fresh install.